# Sword Coast Legends official campaign playable with DM?

Tags: pc, sword-coast-legends

The official campaign shipped in Sword Coast Legends is intended to be played solo (as it is advertised).

The question is: is it possible to play it in group and with an active Dungeon Master? If it's possible, to what extent? Is it barely allowed or maybe it's supported with shared quests, auto-scaling encounters, and (most important) some predispositions for the DM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A campaign can be played in three ways even with the latest update.

1. Solo
2. Friends
3. Public

In all of the above, you can play with up to three more people either from your Steam Friend List or other people logged into the game. However to have a Dungeon Master join the game you have to be in Dungeon Crawl mode or Custom Module.

To sum it up, a Dungeon Master cannot join you in the Official Campaign.